# How to add an extra Header with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, html-email, pear

I'm a newbie with PEAR modules and I'm trying to send an email with attachment. The mail works but when I use special characters like accents I received weird symbols:

Original word: Tiburón
Word Received: tiburÃ³n

I read that I miss to add UTF-8 encode to my email, so I tried to include the following line:

```
$headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Below is the code that I'm using but it's not working, I'm still getting the weird symbols:

```
$message = new Mail_mime(); 
$message->setTXTBody($text); 
$body = $message->get();
$extraheaders = array("From"=>$from, "Subject"=>$subject,"Reply-To"=>$visitor_email,"CC"=>$bccemail, "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");
$send = $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Did my syntax for $extraheaders is correct? I have tried also to find a simple tutorial but I did not have any luck. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

See the user comments on the [documentation page](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php):

```
$mimeparams = array();
$mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
$mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8"; 

$headers = array();
$headers['From'] = 'foo@example.org;
$headers['To']   = 'bar@example.org;
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test;
$headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]= "8bit";

$body = $mime->get($mimeparams); 
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
```